# Azure DevOps Release Pipeline not triggering after new artifact is published

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a fairly simple build pipeline configured in Azure DevOps. It builds an ASP.NET Core MVC web application, then publishes that artifact for release.

This is the build YAML:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main
  paths:
    exclude:
      - azure-pipelines.yml

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build 'MyWebApp' --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  displayName: 'Build Web in $(buildConfiguration)'

- script: cp -a $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/**/wwwroot/. $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/wwwroot/
  displayName: 'Copy web assets to Staging'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
  displayName: 'Publish Build Artifact'
```

The build is triggering automatically whenever code is merged to `main`, just as expected & I can see the artifact being produced.

I've then set up a release pipeline with the continuous deployment trigger enabled against this build pipeline. No branch filters have been specified. For the life of me though, this release pipeline does not trigger when the artifact is produced.

If I run the release pipeline manually, it grabs the artifact and performs the deploy without issue. But it's never triggered automatically since creation.

A few things I've checked / tried:

1. Deleting both pipelines & recreating them - build was recreated from the committed YAML, release was rebuilt from scratch.
2. Confirmed I don't have both continuous integration & pull request triggers enabled.
3. Confirmed the YAML trigger in the build pipeline is not being overridden in the editor. I.e., the "Override the YAML continuous integration trigger from here" checkbox is unchecked.

I'm out of ideas of what I could possibly check or change. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is the artifact setup on my Release pipeline:

[image]

And this is the trigger configuration of my Release pipeline:

[image]

Comment: can you also add a screeshot of how the "Artifacts" section of your release pipeline is setup ?

Comment: @Sibtain Added as edit to the original post.

Comment: I created the build and release pipelines exactly (more or less) like you have, but I wasn't able to reproduce your scenario. Try creating the build and release pipeline with the most bare minimum configuration and then try it. If that works, you might be able to come to the root cause.

Comment: Thank you @Sibtain. I've recreated this in a new project with the most basic of setups - the default ASP.NET Core template committed, with a build pipeline to build & publish, then the release pipeline to trigger off the artifact. Even in this "pristine" environment, it does not trigger automatically. Manually creating a release does. Wondering if this might be something with the Organization, as it is very new...

Comment: Yes, it's possible it might be an issue with the organization, you can try this same use case in your personal organization or any other that you might have. I would say to create a ticket in the [Developers Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps) as well.

Comment: Thank you! I've got a ticket up there now too. Will leave this thread & update once I get a response. Appreciate you taking the time to help look into this @Sibtain.